# Query using Cypher to find P who have N friends working at C

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a list of 70+ people (name, profile_id) and the relationships of who is friends with who. I know of 8 which work at company X. But what i am wanting to do is try and establish/predict who else works at company X

My theory is anyone who does not already work at company X but friends with at least 4 people who does has a strong chance of working also for company X.

I have used the below query but doesnt seem to produce the correct results.

```
MATCH (p1:FacebookPerson)-[:FRIEND]->(p2:FacebookPerson)
MATCH (p2:FacebookPerson)-[:WORK_AT]-(c:Company)
RETURN p2,c;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
MATCH (c:Company)<-[:WORKS_AT]-(f)-[:FRIEND]-(p)
WHERE c.name = 'Company X' AND NOT (c)<-[:WORKS_AT]-(p)
WITH p, count(f) as connections
WHERE connections >= 4
RETURN p, connections
```

This finds, per person who is a friend of someone who works at company x (but who does not work there themselves), the count of how many friends of theirs work at company x and filters to those with 4 or more.